# How do i fix name 'lines' is not defined in discord.py?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a password checker command that checks if a password is common but I'm getting name 'lines' is not defined.
Here is the code:

````
import discord, requests, discord_webhook
from discord.ext import commands
from discord_webhook import DiscordEmbed, DiscordWebhook
import requests, aiohttp, datetime
import random
from discord.utils import escape_markdown, escape_mentions
from discord import Embed
from random import choice
import os
import datetime, time
from asyncio import sleep as s
import giphy_client
import json
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from discord.utils import get
from giphy_client.rest import ApiException
import random
import string

print("Working.........Kinda")


client = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix= "!")

please_wait_emb = discord.Embed(title="Please Wait", description="``` Processing Your Request ```", color=0xff0000)
please_wait_emb.set_author(name="YourBot")
please_wait_emb.set_thumbnail(url="https://c.tenor.com/I6kN-6X7nhAAAAAj/loading-buffering.gif")


@client.command()
async def pwdcheck(ctx, *, password):
    loading_message = await ctx.send(embed=please_wait_emb)

    try:
        if password + "\n" in lines: # <- Here is the error
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Password Checker!", color=0xff0000)
            embed.set_author(name="YourBot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/881007500588089404/881046764206039070/unknown.png")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879311068097290320/PngItem_1526969.png")
            embed.add_field(name=f"Your Passoword", value=f"{password}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name=f"Safety", value=f"Not Safe. This password is in the list of most common 10 million passwords!", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
            await loading_message.delete()
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)
        else:
            embed=discord.Embed(title="Password Checker!", color=0xff0000)
            embed.set_author(name="YourBot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/881007500588089404/881046764206039070/unknown.png")
            embed.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879311068097290320/PngItem_1526969.png")
            embed.add_field(name=f"Your Passoword", value=f"{password}", inline=False)
            embed.add_field(name=f"Safety", value=f"Safe. This password is not in the list of most common 10 million passwords!", inline=False)
            embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
            await loading_message.delete()
            await ctx.send(embed=embed)

    except Exception as e:
        embed2=discord.Embed(title=":red_square: Error!", description="The command was unable to run successfully! ", color=0xff0000)
        embed2.set_author(name="YourBot", icon_url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/881007500588089404/881046764206039070/unknown.png")
        embed2.set_thumbnail(url="https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/877796755234783273/879298565380386846/sign-red-error-icon-1.png")
        embed2.add_field(name="Error:", value=f"{e}", inline=False)
        embed2.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}")
        await loading_message.delete()
        await ctx.send(embed=embed2)
````

I tried to fix it but I sadly could not. How do I fix this?

Comment: What do you think `lines` contains?  You haven't defined it anywhere, and of course we can't guess what you intended.

Comment: Your `if` and `else` clauses only differ by one word.  Duplicating code like that is a common source of error.  And, of course you're importing 20 different modules and only using two.

Comment: Also remember that you cannot call your file `discord.py`.  That will conflict with the library module you're trying to import.

Comment: Hey Tim the modules that I added here are for my other commands

Comment: And how can i fix it

Comment: **WE** can't tell you how to fix it.  From the print statements, I'm guessing you expect `lines` to contain the dictionary of 10 million common passwords, but you did not create it.  Do you have such a file?  If so, you need to read it.

Comment: Yes I fixed it i don't know what i was thinking i simply added this 
filepwdlist1 = open("10-million-password-list-top-1000000.txt", "r")
lines = filepwdlist1.readlines()